# How to loop in a helper method and render a partial for each looped instance. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have the following view in my Rails app:

*app/views/matches/_round.html.erb*

```
matches.each do |match|
  # some html code here
  <%= predictions(@pool, match, @current_participant) %>
  # more html code here
end
```

and the following helper method:

*app/helpers/match_predictions_helper.rb*

```
  def predictions(pool, match, participant)
    if match.can_be_predicted_in?(pool)
      random_predictions_for_match = match.random_predictions_in_pool(pool)
      if random_predictions_for_match.empty?
        "<h3> No predictions available yet </h3>".html_safe
      else
        random_predictions_for_match.each do |prediction|
          tooltip_title = "undisclosed participant"
          outcome_class = ""
          render partial: 'match_predictions/prediction', locals: { match: match, prediction: prediction, tooltip_title: tooltip_title, outcome_class: outcome_class }
        end
      end
    else
      match.predictions_in_pool(pool, current_user).each do |prediction|
        tooltip_title = prediction.participant.username
        outcome_class = prediction.class_name
        render partial: 'match_predictions/prediction', locals: { match: match, prediction: prediction, tooltip_title: tooltip_title, outcome_class: outcome_class }
      end
    end
  end
```

So what I'm intending with this is to show a list of predictions for each match but that list changes depending on some conditions. I could achieve this by including the logic in the view like:

*app/views/matches/_round.html.erb*

```
matches.each do |match|
<% if match.can_be_predicted_in?(@pool) %>
  <% random_predictions_for_match = match.random_predictions_in_pool(@pool) %>
  <% if random_predictions_for_match.empty? %>
    <h3> No predictions to spy available yet </h3>
  <% else %>
    <% random_predictions_for_match.each do |prediction| %>
      <% tooltip_title = "undisclosed participant" %>
      <% outcome_class = "" %>
      <%= render partial: 'match_predictions/prediction', locals: { match: match, prediction: prediction, tooltip_title: tooltip_title, outcome_class: outcome_class } %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  #etc, etc, the rest of the code below.
end
```

I'd like, however, to strip the logic out of the view. What I've encountered so far is that when putting the `each` loop inside the helper I get returned, in my view, an array with all the objects that were looped and not the expected partial rendered for each looped item. The helper is outputting the loop itself instead of what's in it (i.e. the partial to be rendered').  Oddly, in my server log I see the partial being rendered for each iteration.

I've often used helpers and partials to render objects that result of loop iterations but I've noticed I'm not quite getting how `render` and helpers work while trying to stuck a loop in a helper.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Closer to solution, based on Taryn suggestion below**

So as the output of the `predictions` helper would be an array, you'd have to loop through it in the view so I did.

```
matches.each do |match|
<% predictions(@pool, match, @current_participant).each do |prediction| %>
  <%= prediction %>
<% end %>
end
```

Also, for the same reason, the first conditional output that was a string should be put into the `results` array as well:

```
# more code here
if random_predictions_for_match.empty?
  results << ["<h3> No predictions to spy available yet </h3>".html_safe]
else
# more code here
```

I still had issues as the browser wouldn't read the partial rendered content as html so for now I've moved all the partial content to another helper which is now called where the partial was called. This works and reduced the logic in the view except for the extra `predictions` each loop.

Any more suggestions to clean code appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly a total tangent: did you know you don't have to open/close the `<%` tags for every LOC? They work across multiple lines... which will reduce some of the noise in your template eg:

```
<% matches.each do |match|
 if match.can_be_predicted_in?(@pool)
   random_predictions_for_match = match.random_predictions_in_pool(@pool) 
   if random_predictions_for_match.empty? %>
    <h3> No predictions to spy available yet </h3>
  <% else 
     random_predictions_for_match.each do |prediction| 
       tooltip_title = "undisclosed participant" 
       outcome_class = "" %>
      <%= render partial: 'match_predictions/prediction', locals: { match: match, prediction: prediction, tooltip_title: tooltip_title, outcome_class: outcome_class } %>
    <% end 
   end 
 else %>
  # etc, etc, the rest of the code below.
<% end %>
```

Secondly, the return value of a method (even for helpers), is the last statement in the method... which in this case is the loop itself, not the render that is called inside your loop. This is why rails thinks you are intending to display the loop's return-value...

You may have to store the results of your renders and then return them at the end, I'm guessing (this is not bug-tested) something like:

```
  def predictions(pool, match, participant)
    results = []
    if match.can_be_predicted_in?(pool)
      random_predictions_for_match = match.random_predictions_in_pool(pool)
      if random_predictions_for_match.empty?
        return "<h3> No predictions available yet </h3>".html_safe
      else
        random_predictions_for_match.each do |prediction|
          tooltip_title = "undisclosed participant"
          outcome_class = ""
          results << render(partial: 'match_predictions/prediction', locals: { match: match, prediction: prediction, tooltip_title: tooltip_title, outcome_class: outcome_class })
        end
      end
    else
      match.predictions_in_pool(pool, current_user).each do |prediction|
        tooltip_title = prediction.participant.username
        outcome_class = prediction.class_name
        results << render(partial: 'match_predictions/prediction', locals: { match: match, prediction: prediction, tooltip_title: tooltip_title, outcome_class: outcome_class })
      end
    end
    results
  end
```

Comment: Taryn thanks a lot for your advice. It definitely make sense. For some reason I was closed to the option of collecting rendered partials in an array. 
I've tried your suggested solution, however, and I get a syntax error of the kind you get when if statements or blocks are not closed appropriately. I've checked and the issue is definitely with the lines where the rendered partials are pushed into the arrays `results <<...etc.`. I've tried adding parentheses and changing them to other places without success. Any ideas why would the syntax be wrong.

Comment: hmmm... maybe it's expecting it to be a string instead... eg `results = ""` and `results += ...` I'd test it by starting with rending something simple (eg a string with the prediction id instead of a partial template) and check that all the rest of the logic works... then add back the render without locals... and see at what point it breaks.

Comment: Thanks Taryn. I'm giving it another try right now. It must be something simple. It's puzzling me as at some point it worked, I couldn't see what was it and lost the change god knows how. I'll follow your debugging suggestion and see if I'm lucky

Comment: I've got the error. I thought spaces in Ruby didn't matter. Not in this case! I added a space between `render` and the first parenthesis. 
The helper is now returning an array with each rendered partial. However, the browser is not reading it as HTML. I've tried to use `html_safe` at the end of the partial helper, hoping for an easy fix, without success. 
I could solve the whole issue by calling another helper instead of rendering a partial so at the end I'll be able to leave my view without logic. However if you can suggest a last Rails magic trick to solve this would be appreciated

Comment: Rethinking about the problem actually the issue is that with your proposed approach, regardless if I'm collecting partials or other helper output in the array, the output of the helper inside the matches `each` loop will always be an array. Meaning I'll have to loop through it in my main view and that when the helper method doesn't output an array (as it's the case of the first conditional it would break the code if not placed into another array. I'll try this and report if it worked.

Comment: Yeah you don't want it to be an array, but to have been rendered into a string of html already... OTTOMH I'm not sure how to make that happen (it's been a while since we used helpers). TBH I'd think about a partial that will take the collection and loop it inside the partial (just pass which set of objects as a local) - or possibly look into `render collection`  rather than looping?